# Href link and linking

Tags: php, html

Ok so i have a little problem now, that i hope someone would be able to help me resolve.

I've made a website in html, and after finishing the design i decided to break it up in php include lines where it would be easier to navigate and continue to code.

For example:

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And after breaking it up:

PHP code

```
include 'php/head.php';
include 'php/body.php';
```

It would all be OK if i didn't had to make a sub menu's and categories in another folder. The main problem is that i have folder tree like this:

```
nslife(root)
   images
   css
   js
   php
   novisad(folder that contains the sub categories)
   index.php
```

Ok so building the page as i did by breaking the code up works excellent on the main index page but after copy/pasting the same code on to another new page which is a sub category all of the href links didn't work.

For example:
Primary index page:

```
<img id="right-img" src="images/baners/baner500x60.jpg">
```

But after using it in my Secondary page from the sub folder "novisad" the image doesn't show.

I know it has to do something with ../ or // or anything else but tried every possibility and nothing works, and if it works for one page i doesn't work on another.

Comment: why dont you just use the absolute path?

Comment: doesn't "../images/baners/baner500x60.jpg" solve this issue? I may be wrong!

Comment: absolute path would be ok but it would be really hard to use it in my situation seeing that i have a lot of includes similar to that problem.

Ohh and "../" takes me waaay further than the root folder.

Comment: use some PHP $SERVER_ in front of the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my programming I set a variable called: `$level = '';` which is set at the top of the page.

At the top level it is: $level = '';

Sub Folder it is set as: $level = '../';

Sub Sub Folder it is set as: $level = '../../';

and so forth. Then you simple prepend the all links with the variable.

```
$level.'css/style';
```

all of your links will respond correctly as a result.

For larger projects I do this on my conn page:

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_username = "????"; 
    $db_pass = "????"; 
    $db_name = "????";

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));

    //$site_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];    
    $site_url = 'http://localhost/demo';

    # this page stuff   
    $pg_uri = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pg_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $this_file = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php");
    $file_name = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

    # urls      
    $u_inc = $site_url.'/inc';  
    $u_panels = $site_url.'/panels';            
    $u_legal = $u_inc.'/legal';
    $u_forms = $u_inc.'/forms';              
    $u_admin = $site_url.'/admin';
    $u_plugin = $site_url.'/plugins';        
    $u_js = $site_url.'/js';    
    $u_regions = $site_url.'/regions';
    $u_menus = $site_url.'/menus';

    # paths
    $p_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];     
    $p_inc = $level.'inc';
    $p_panels = $level.'panels';
    $p_legal = $p_inc.'/legal';              
    $p_forms = $p_inc.'/forms';
    $p_admin = $level.'admin';              
    $p_plugin = $level.'plugins';
    $p_js = $level.'js';                    
    $p_regions = $level.'regions';  
    $p_menus = $level.'menus';
```

Once the vars are committed to memory it flows with the rest of your programming.

Comment: Now I'm really frustrated that the solution was that simple...
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Potential solutions:**

1. Update all links to use an absolute path, or use `../` (which traverses up 1 level) to get to the right directory. Or use a single `/` to indicate the root directory at the start of every path.
2. Define some constant like `ROOT_URL`, setting it equal to the root address of your site, and prepend this to every path in your code
3. Use: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and prepend this to your paths

[Here's a good article](http://css-tricks.com/php-include-from-root/) on the subject which you might like to read.

Comment: Just to make sure of this, i can make a $path =www.mydomain.com in init.php file which i include in every single page on my website, and then in every single place where i have  a path i just use "<?php echo $path?>images/baners/baner500x60.jpg"

Comment: Essentially yep, although when using it you'd use: `<a href="<?php echo $path; ?>/images/...">`

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using relative urls, so when you reference `images/baners/baner500x60.jpg`, you need to have a folder called `images` in the same directory as your file that is referencing that location.

For your purposes, use absolute urls instead.  Something like `http://www.yourdomain.com/images/baners/baner500x60.jpg`.  These will always reference the same location regardless of the location of the file that's referencing it.

Comment: Ha! That's what I get for taking so long to edit my answer. You got yours in well before mine.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need the absolute path. Your code would be referring to a file like `images/image.jpg` but from the subfolder the actual path would be `../images/image.jpg`. To fix this, use `http://yoursite.com/images/image.jpg`. You may run into issues if your site sees these as external links and won't run scripts from them as a result, in which case you need to find an alternate solution (different includes for that folder, or modify the includes so that you rewrite the links depending on depth of the subfolder).

Answer (score 0):

For the img src attribute, use an absolute url instead of a relative url, like so:

```
<img id='right-img' src='http://www.domain.com/nslife/images/baners/baner500x60.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full address http://url.com/images/images.png or put ../images/image.png to move up one level in the URL.